# how to determine why ios app crashes on iOS 13 at start

Tags: ios, ios13

I am having a hard time trying to determine why my app crashes when being downloaded via testflight on iOS devices. If I upload it via xcode to simulator or physical devices it works as expected; when downloaded via testflight to ios13 devices (ios12 are ok) it crashes at the very startup, it seems when asking for permissions.

The only permissions asked are notification and microphone, however after the crash I went to the settings panel and see that microphone has not been granted, while notification is.
So I supposed that there was a problem with mic permission and deleted it form Info.plist: nothing changed, it crashes nonetheless so, maybe it's not the mic.

Also i have exported the ipa for adhoc distribution and to my huge surprise OTA installation via https on a local webserver works without problems.

Any ideas how can I determine what's going on? Btw in the testflight crash report there is no stacktrace or whatever helpful info, just the info about the device (model, memory battery, etc.)

Comment: A common reason for this is that your app takes too long to launch. See https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=testflight+crash+launch However, without any of the info, that's just a guess.

Comment: A symbolcated crash logs might be helpful. Try to get it from device if you have from device only.

Comment: @Mehdi - The Xcode tag doesn't belong on this question. This is not a question about the Xcode IDE.

Comment: @Rob You're right, I didn't understand the question correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to share my experience, in case someone else has the same problem.

The issue was caused by an old unused component in the storyboard.
There was a deprecated UISearchDisplayController and that was triggering some interaction with tetflight delivery. The same IPA distributed via adhoc server was not causing any problem.

Maybe Testflight delivery does now some kind of optimization that was clashing with the deprecated component?

However, simply removing the component solved the crash.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply find out the exact issue by getting you device crash log in:

- **Organizer ->Select your app -> Crashes**
  [image]
- or you can download device log to get the exact issue by following below steps:
  [image]
  [image]

Comment: there was no crash whatsoever listed that could help me with the issue